# PDFKit gem can not hide link - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, pdfkit

---

Hello people

I was following [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit) to generate a "pdf" file from a view in my rails app. Everything was ok, until I tried to hide the "link to download". Everytime I generate the PDF file, the link is still shown. I think that the "@media print" style in the css file is not working.

Is there another way to hide the link in the generated pdf file?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It is answered here http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit. Check section application.css

You need to give an id for the "link to download" then in the CSS file hide the element using display: none. In the above example the id name is pdf_link and css properties are defined like this -

```
 #pdf_link{ display: none; }
```

That should work.

Comment: I did that. Actually, I followed the same railscast, but it didn't work. I think there's something wrong with "@media print"